# Did f2pool manipulate transactions during the Status ICO?

Tags: transactions, mining-pools, attacks, frontrunning

Blocks such as [this one](https://etherscan.io/txs?block=3903912) and [this one](https://etherscan.io/block/3903913) appear to show preferential treatment being given to f2pool transactions in blocks mined by f2pool during the beginning of the Status ICO (at block height 3903900).

Further details are being collected [in this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6itye9/collecting_information_about_f2pool/).

**Is there a reasonable explanation for f2pool's block contents during the Status ICO, or does this constitute strong evidence of transaction manipulation and/or frontrunning?**

Comment: The contracts were deployed well in advance, the final parameters of dynamic ceiling were shown half an hour before the ICO start. So everybody knew how to proceed. I'd not say manipulation but miners run for a profit, they were missing fees on the higher priced transactions, but they bet the token will be more valuable later. In other coins it is suspected that miners can be 'bribed' to privilege certain txs.